# Dracaena Cane is dying please help

Tags: diagnosis, watering

Heyyy. I bought this beautiful plant in the summer and it has been through a lot between moving n being knocked over to a few weeks of no watering. It was still healthy though! Recently it’s been dying on me and I thought it was lack of sunlight but there’s no change. Please help!!!![image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This plant is a [Dracaena fragrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_fragrans) or the corn plant. The way it is grown is to let a large specimen grow outdoors and then use a chainsaw to cut it into shorter segments which are potted up in a greenhouse and then sold to the consumer.

The problem with this is that the plant does not have a lot of time to develop a mature root system. New plants are vulnerable to lower light levels found in a home and irregular watering which can dry out the root system.

I suggest:

- move to higher light
- water on a regular schedule: add enough water till it runs out the bottom of the pot and then let the top inch dry
- do not fertilize for a year
- be patient: these plants bud readily from the stalk but need time to do so

You can tell if the plant is dead by grasping the stem in your hand.  If the plant is dead there will be a space between the core and the bark and the bark will be dry and papery.